# How can I access nested data from my JSON object in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

I am attempting to map a large amount of data in React with which Iv'e had a decent amount of success with. Now i'm attempting to retrieve data from a nested JSON object and I have no idea how to. My JSON data is below.

```
{
    "core-topics": [
        {
            "id": "coding",
            "name": "Coding",
            "headerColour": "blue",
            "description": "Learn how to build your very own website!",
            "image": "https://www.bitdegree.org/tutorials/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/what-is-a-web-developer.jpg",
            "link": [
                {
                    "id": "coding-item-one",
                    "name": "Java"
                },
                {
                    "id": "coding-item-two",
                    "name": "C++"
                },
                {
                    "id": "coding-item-three",
                    "name": "Python"
                }
            ]
        },
```

I'm accessing this data using a method that searches for a specific component id and then returns the matching data.

```
const Writer = ({match: {url}, coreTopics}) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            /* This renders each link from the JSON file */
            /* And maps it onto the card layout component below */
            <Route path = {`${url}/:topicId`} render = {
                /* searches for a matching id and renders all properties if it finds a match */
                ({ match }) => 
                <card {...coreTopics.find(topic => topic.id === match.params.topicId)}/>}/>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

While using a template component to render all of the JSON data to a HTML format.

```
class card extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            links: {}
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <Container>
                <HeaderImage headerImage = {this.props.image}>
                    <ImageTextContainer>
                        <H1> {this.props.name} </H1>
                        <Stripe stripeColour = {this.props.headerColour}/>
                        <P> {this.props.description} </P>
                    </ImageTextContainer>


                    /* What I'm attempting to do with 0 luck. */
                    /* I am also aware the code isn't correct, i'm just demonstrating my logic behind this. */

                    <ul> 
                      {this.props.link.map((name, id)) => 
                          <li id = {link.id}> {link.name} </li>
                       })
                    </ul>
                </HeaderImage>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

Each time I try to access the properties within the link object, I get an error saying that the map function cannot be used on undefined. It is basically impossible to get any data out of this object and I have no idea why. I can access all of the data easily except any nested objects.

Any help at all is appreciated! I understand this is quite a large post and probably includes too much information but I couldn't think of another way to get this all across to anyone who might be able to help.

Comment: I don't think it's clear for when you are passing your JSON object to the Writer component. For example, you are not looking in `core-topics` array anywhere in the code you posted.... I would have expected to see `yourJsonObject["core-topics"].find(({id}) => id === matchMedia.params.topicId)` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, it isn't clear where or how you are passing in the JSON object you listed. But for an example, if I had this object, and wanted to write a function that would return a matching topic... I would write something like this:

```js
const coreTopicsJson = {
  "core-topics": [
      {
          "id": "coding",
          "name": "Coding",
          "headerColour": "blue",
          "description": "Learn how to build your very own website!",
          "image": "https://www.bitdegree.org/tutorials/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/what-is-a-web-developer.jpg",
          "link": [
              {
                  "id": "coding-item-one",
                  "name": "Java"
              },
              {
                  "id": "coding-item-two",
                  "name": "C++"
              },
              {
                  "id": "coding-item-three",
                  "name": "Python"
              }
          ]
      }
  ]
}

const findTopicById = (topicId, coreTopicsJson) => (
  coreTopicsJson["core-topics"].find(({id}) => id === topicId)
)

const codingCoreTopic = findTopicById("coding", coreTopicsJson) // returns object of topic with id of 'coding'
```

Perhaps this might help on how to pull data from the JSON object?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! this unfortunately doesn't seem to do the trick and returns an error saying coreTopicsJson isn't a function.

Answer (score 1):

Update the Card component to take data using prop key, do not spread it.

```
class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          links: {}
      }
  }
  render(){
    const card = this.props.card || {link: []}
      return(
          <Container>
              <HeaderImage headerImage = {card.image}>
                  <ImageTextContainer>
                      <H1> {card.name} </H1>
                      <Stripe stripeColour = {card.headerColour}/>
                      <P> {card.description} </P>
                  </ImageTextContainer>
              </HeaderImage>
          </Container>
      )
  }
}
```

**Pass data using key(prop)**

```
const Writer = ({match: {url}, coreTopics}) => {
  const card = coreTopics.find(topic => topic.id === match.params.topicId)
  return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <Route path = {`${url}/:topicId`} render = {
              ({ match }) => 
              <card card={card}/>}/>
      </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! seems to be a viable solution, however  I am now getting "match undefined" in the Writer Component when I switch from spreading to your method. Any idea of how to get around this without spreading the props?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: can u update question with latest code after modification.